# Collection of Objects Passing a new UDT to each Object while Looping thru an Array

Tags: excel, object, collections, user-defined-types, vba

My `aMRecon` array is 2500 rows x 65 columns. I need to evaluate up to 10+ columns within each single row and thus I believe I need to create an object representing each row. I have created a `UDT` and in a basic procedure below I am trying to create an `object for each row` with each object having an `.EntityID` property (which is the cell value in each row within `Column B` or `Column 2`).

```
Public Type BreakInfo
    EntityID As String
    IssueName As String  
    ValDate As Date
    LedgerAMT As Long
    NetAMTL As Long
    PriceDiff As Long                    
End Type

Sub Fill_Objects()

Dim aMrow As Integer, aMcol As Integer
Dim BI As BreakInfo

For aMcol = LBound(aMRecon, 2) To UBound(aMRecon, 2)
        For aMrow = LBound(aMRecon, 1) To UBound(aMRecon, 1)
                If aMcol = 2 Then
                    Debug.Print aMRecon(aMrow, aMcol)
                    Set ObjLSL = New Collection
                    BI.EntityID = aMRecon(aMrow, aMcol)
                End If
        Next aMrow
    Next aMcol
End If

End Sub
```

Do I need to somehow create a collection of objects? Could someone please show me an example to help. As of right now I think I only have one object and the `.EntityID` property keeps getting overwritten. Thank you

**In Fact each row at will only have 1 property, basically each property is a Column Header. Am I going about this the most efficient way? Eventually I will need to evaluate each property within an object and categorize it.**

Inserted a ClassModule entitle `BreakInfo`

```
'Public EntityID As String
Public EntityID As Variant
Public IssueName As String  
Public ValDate As Date
Public LedgerAMT As Long
Public NetAMTL As Long
Public PriceDiff As Long
```

That's all that's in the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first create (insert) a Class Module, name it BreakInfo, and give it Public members like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public EntityID As String
Public IssueName As String
Public ValDate As Date
Public LedgerAMT As Long
Public NetAMTL As Long
Public PriceDiff As Long
```

Then you can use something like this:

```
Sub Fill_Objects()
    Dim aMrow As Integer, aMcol As Integer
    Dim BI As BreakInfo
    Dim ObjLSL As Collection
    Dim key As Long

    'Create the Collection instance.
    Set ObjLSL = New Collection

    For aMcol = LBound(aMRecon, 2) To UBound(aMRecon, 2)
        For aMrow = LBound(aMRecon, 1) To UBound(aMRecon, 1)
            If aMcol = 2 Then
                'Instantiate a BreakInfo.
                Set BI = New BreakInfo
                BI.EntityID = aMRecon(aMrow, aMcol)
                '...

                key = key + 1
                ObjLSL.Add BI, CStr(key)
            End If
        Next aMrow
    Next aMcol
End Sub
```

Notice that the collection is instantiated once, before the loops. A collection can't ingest variables of user-defined types, but it will gladly gobble up object instances.

**Edit**

The question has changed. If you worry about efficiency, you could hardcode `aMcol = 2` and do without the outer `For` and the `If aMcol = 2`. Other than that, I don't understand what you're trying to do with your values.

Comment: How come a class and not a public type? One line `ObjLSL.Add BI, key` I am getting a type mismatch error? I thought it was due to String data type mismatch and tested with `Public EntityID as Variant` and changed to `BI.EntityID = CStr(aMRecon(aMrow, aMcol))` but still receive the error. I did Create a new Class titled BreakInfo and update my post showing the class contents.

Comment: Collections can't ingest user-defined types. If you do prefer working with UDTs, you can work with arrays of them, e.g. `Dim arrUDT(0 To 999) As MyUDT`. Then you can refer to any element, e.g. `arrUDT(25).MyField`.

Comment: Apparently an Object's key can only be a `String` changed to `ObjLSL.Add BI, CStr(key)` ..Any thoughts?

Comment: My bad. Will amend my answer. I must admit I don't use Collections at all, using Scripting.Dictionary instead, which takes just about any type as a key and offers the ever useful Exists method.